# Cant start mysql in safe mode to recover root password

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean

I am currentley trying to start mysql in safe mode to recover the password for root.

I am following this [guide here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-and-reset-a-root-password-in-mysql):

Here is the error I get:

[image]

I have also tried

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Comment: Try `sudo ps aux | grep mysql`. What output do you see?

Comment: *digitalocean* has a lot of incomplete articles (and as another similar site it comes near the top of google searches). As for Q&A, you're at the right spot - different site though (dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the password for the root user by using this command.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-*
```

mysql-server version is what version you have installed.

You can try pressing tab for options.

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that one mysql server is already started on your computer when you try to start another one in safe mode. First shutdown previous instance of mysql server.